# Signal detection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-series, signal-processing

I'm currently working on has an hobby on vdl2 signal. I've acquired the data below:
[image: graph]

My problem is I can't find any algorithm who can help me distinct the usefull data from the noise.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: without more info (like what you consider useful data and noise) we can only guess ... usual approaches are threshold `max-min` in some sliding window  or threshold sliding average crossing some value ...

Comment: Excuse me if I wasn't precise enough. My usefull data is between 1447 and 2703.

Comment: I would use FIFO holding at least 1024 samples (assuming you x axis values are samples) and use it for computing abs sliding average ... whenever the result is above `0.5` you are processing useful signal ... however the start will be detected shifted by some fraction of the sliding window size (FIFO size) ... similarly the end will be also shifted in the same way

Comment: I'm going to try it. I'll keep in touch.

Comment: note that by using FIFO you do not need to sum up all the samples of the sliding window each new sample ... you just add to the avg newly added value to FIFO and substract the outgoing one so its `O(1)` time at the cost of `O(n)` space ... also by using power of 2 FIFO size you can just bitshift instead of dividing ...